# Why Windows download under VirtualBox is 20x faster than in native Linux?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, download, youtube-dl

I'm using Linux Debian Jessie 64-bit (Host), and have Windows 7 (Guest) running on Oracle VirtualBox. I'm using youtube-dl to download a video from YouTube. Since a friend asked me how to use it and she uses Windows, I tried the same on VirtualBox to teach her. To my surprise, the download via the Linux Terminal  was running at 200KB/s while the download at Windows terminal ran at 4MB/s! I must assume that something is wrong in my configuration, but I have no idea of what could it be. Or is there any other explanation?

[image]

Comment: it's likely that you didn't change the default network card for linux or you didn't install virtualbox addon for linux which results in a crappy driver implementation on linux.

Comment: @Kiwy Linux is not running in VirtualBox.

Comment: Then I would guest that there's a problem with the soft

Comment: Maybe virtual box is making some processes(which might be using bandwidth) to pause

Comment: Or with Youtube itself. https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/15271

Comment: @user5954246 The Linux download speed was the same before I even opened VirtualBox.

Comment: @Kiwy With YouTube?! So you're suggesting they're messing with Linux users, while giving Windows users VIP treatment? That wouldn't be news, though...

Comment: what I suggest is that you shouldn't await any consistency for download speed from Google as they have thousands of serveur serving files and that depending on the file the location of the file at a specific time if the file is in cache or not, the speed your ISP is having with some portion of the public IP on Internet If you use IPv6/V4... So much could go on here 20x speed difference wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that **you are connected to two different YouTube servers**, and are not even downloading the same file (the title is the same, but the sizes are very different, and both are reported in the same unit - MiB).

To investigate, I would:

- check whether repeated runs of the same download go at the same speed.
- verify whether it's always the same "www.youtube.com" that gets hit, by forcing its IP in the hosts file.
- force either -4 or -6 option in both Linux and Windows (the defaults might be different).
- try downloading something else, say a kernel from kernel.org, and maybe test various sites.
- check whether Linux has some kind of proxy/traffic shaper/throttle installed

This ought to circumscribe whether it's a network problem, a path problem, an operating system problem, a happenstance, a coincidence, or a third option.

Comment: Different servers giving 20x different speeds? I don't think so. Will look at your other suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Large MTUs don't typically work over the Internet, and Jumbo Frames are also specific to gigabit ethernet LANs.

Comment: @Rodrigo: If one server is 100 km from you and the other is 10 000 km away (and maybe a slower system to begin with, and maybe more heavily loaded), why do you rule out a 20× difference?

Comment: Indeed, trying to download again now, a few hours later, gave me a 4MB/s speed. It probably was a server issue.